# what is the use of form[#special] in a drupal form?

Tags: forms

Now i'm working with forms and trying to add template in to it, I have form['#special'], but i don't know how to set it and what's the use of that and its usage.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can embed anything in your form. Just add `#` at the beginning of the array index to indicate it's not a child element, and Form API will accept that even if it does not define or use it. [Form API reference](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7) does not mention `#special`, so it is not an standard parameter. Instead, it's a parameter created by module's author for his own need.

For example, I usually add `#machine_name` to anything that can trigger AJAX, for easier handling of `$form_state['triggering_element']`. There are many uses.