# prevent submit in ajax call

Tags: forms

I have a form  with 2 submit in it, one of them is a button to generate codes, everytimes I click on generate form_submited called up and a record insert in db, how can I prevent form_sumit in ajax triggering?

```
function rah_cc_generate_form($form,$form_state){
    $form=array();

    $form['gen']=array(
        '#type' => 'fieldset',
        '#name' =>t('generate gift card code'),
        '#collapsible' => TRUE,
        '#collapsed' => false,
//        '#weight' => 5,

    );
    $form['gen']['code']=array(
            '#type' => 'textfield',
            '#title' => t('gift code'),
            '#default_value' => '',
            '#prefix' => '<div id="gc-code">',
            '#suffix' => '</div>',
            '#size' => variable_get('rah_gc_code_size', 8),
            '#maxlength' => 20,
            //'#required' => TRUE,
    );
    $form['gen']['price']=array(
            '#type' => 'textfield',
            '#title' => t('price'),
            '#default_value' => 10000,
            '#size' => 10,
            '#maxlength' => 20,
            '#required' => TRUE,
    );
    $form['gen']['status'] = array(
  '#type' => 'checkbox',
  '#title' => t('status'),
    '#default_value' => 1,
);

    $form['gen']['random']=array(
     '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('generate'),
    '#description' => t("if you want generate random use this plz"),
    //'#weight' => 1,
    //'#submit' => array('rah_cc_generate_random'), // If no javascript action.
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => 'rah_cc_generate_ajax',
      'wrapper' => 'gc-code',
      'method' => 'replace',
      'effect' => 'fade',
      ),
   );


    $form['gen']['save']=array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' =>t('save'),
         );
    ym($form);    
    return $form;


}
function rah_cc_generate_ajax(&$form,$form_state){

    //return $form['gen']['code']['#default_value']=33;
     $form['gen']['code']['#value']=rah_cc_generate();
     //$form_state['values']['code']['und'][0]['value']=44;
     return $form['gen']['code'];

}
```

**update**
I use      `'prevent'=> 'sumbit',` but not get answer :(

```
 $form['gen']['random']=array(
     '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('generate'),
    '#description' => t("if you want generate random use this plz"),
    //'#weight' => 1,
    //'#submit' => array('rah_cc_generate_random'), // If no javascript action.
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => 'rah_cc_generate_ajax',
      'wrapper' => 'gc-code',
      'method' => 'replace',
      'effect' => 'fade',
      'prevent'=> 'sumbit',
      ),
   );
```

[image]

Comment: "submit" is misspelled in your edit, could that have been something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$form_state variable holds 'triggering_element' element which indicates what button triggered (or also you can use #clicked_button element), example (in ajax callback function):

```
function my_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  //dpm($form_state);
  if($form_state['triggering_element']['#value'] == 'MY_ELEMENT\'S_NAME') {
    //do_operation();
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks. I dsm $$form_state['triggering_element'] and findout I should compare it with #value, tnx for your big clue

Comment: @zhilevan Not at all.

Comment: but #name return op for me :).how over tnx for your clue.

Comment: @zhilevan see [here](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/81251/16495) for a way I use to separate user-displayed value from application logic.